# Linux kernel Device Tree cyclic dependency issue

Tags: linux-kernel, circular-dependency, device-tree

When I tested Lnux kernel, dvi and tfp410 are not probed in BeagleBoard. After investigation I found they are cyclic dependency in the Device Tree, I have tried new `fw_devlink_create_devlink()` and other approaches, I can't solve it yet, here is a piece of dependency nodes, dvi_connector_in and tfp410_out are dependent each other.

```dts
tfp410: encoder0 {
    compatible = "ti,tfp410";
    powerdown-gpios = <&twl_gpio 2 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;

    /* XXX pinctrl from twl */

    ports {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        port@0 {
            reg = <0>;

            tfp410_in: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&dpi_out>;
            };
        };

        port@1 {
            reg = <1>;

            tfp410_out: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&dvi_connector_in>;
            };
        };
    };
};

dvi0: connector0 {
    compatible = "dvi-connector";
    label = "dvi";

    digital;

    ddc-i2c-bus = <&i2c3>;

    port {
        dvi_connector_in: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&tfp410_out>;
        };
    };
};
```

Any recommendations are much appreciated.

Comment: `fw_devlink_create_devlink()` is about power management. It would not solve your problem, but by accident..